# Cut matching line and X successive lines until newline and paste into file

Tags: text, awk, sed, gnu

I would like to match all lines from a file containing a word, and take all lines under until coming two two newline characters in a row.

I have the following sed code to cut and paste specific lines, but not subsequent lines:

```
sed 's|.*|/\\<&\\>/{w results\nd}|' teststring | sed -file.bak -f - testfile
```

How could I modify this to take all subsequent lines?

For example, say I wanted to match lines with 'dog', the following should take the first 3 lines of the 5:

```
The best kind of an animal is a dog, for sure
-man's best friend
-related to wolves

Racoons are not cute
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that regexp works to match, but how to move into new file and delete from original file with awk?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in this case I was using take to mean 'cut', to cut and paste into a newfile. so those 3 lines would not be present in testfile but would be in newfile

Comment: So, it is not solved yet? Please edit the question to include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '/dog/ {f=1} /^$/ {f=0} f {print > "new"} !f {print > "tmp"}' file && mv tmp file
```

It will set `f` to true if word `dog` is found, then if a blank line is found set `f` to false.
If `f` is true, print to `new` file.
If `f` is false, print to `tmp` file.
Copy `tmp` file to original file

Edit: Can be shorten some:

```
awk '/dog/ {f=1} /^$/ {f=0} {print > (f?"new":"tmp")}' file && mv tmp file
```

Edit2:  as requested add space for every section in the `new` file:

```
awk '/dog/ {f=1;print ""> "new"} /^$/ {f=0} {print > (f?"new":"tmp")}' file && mv tmp file
```

If the original files does contains tabs or spaces instead of just a blank line after each dog section, change from `/^$/` to `/^[ \t]*$/`

Comment: Actually this seems to be taking a lot of lines that don't match the term...how can I help troubleshoot?

Comment: @JakeRankin  Kan you give example input that does not work?

Comment: I am having trouble providing sample input. When I am using on a big file (300k textfile), it seem most of the lines match even though they don't, as they end up in the newfile. When I take the last 10 lines and test with, it seems to work as it should though.

Comment: Is there a way to add a newline/blank line after each section that is matched and cut/pasted into a new file?

Comment: @JakeRankin  See edit2.  It add a blink line before every section in the new file

Comment: it works perfectly thank you. One question if I wanted to modify to 'copy' instead of 'cut', I would just remove `!f {print > "tmp"}'` and the double ampersands and everything after?

Comment: Also I wonder if there is a switch to make it case insensitive?

Comment: @JakeRankin If you change `/dog/` to `tolower($0) ~ /dog/` it will search for both `dog`, `Dog` and `DOG` etc.  Not sure what you ask for in `copy`.  If you remove `&& mv tmp file` you get three file.  Original `file`, `new` file and `tmp` file.

Comment: Thank you for case insensitive addition. I just want to make a version that can write matches to newfile and not remove anything from old file

Comment: @JakeRankin Then you can make it simpler like this:  `awk '/dog/ {f=1} /^$/ {f=0} f' file >new`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|/\\<&\\>/ba|' stringFile | 
sed -f - -e 'b;:a;w resultFile' -e 'n;/^$/!ba' file
```

Build a set of regexps from the stringFile and send matches to `:a`. Then write the matched line and any further lines until an empty line (or end of file) to the resultFile.

N.B. The results could be sent directly to resultFile,using:

```
sed 's#.*#/\\<&\\>/ba#' stringFile |
sed -nf - -e 'b;:a;p;n;/^$/!ba' file > resultFile
```

To cut the matches from the original file use:

```
sed 's|.*|/\\<&\\>/ba|' stringFile |
sed -f - -e 'b;:a;N;/\n\s*$/!ba;w resultFile' -e 's/.*//p;d' file
```

Comment: Would this remove the matching lines from the original file also?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, to cut the original file see the third solution

Comment: This is probably a stupid question but I'm not sure where to put the term to match. Is it in place of `<&` ?

Comment: The words to match go in the stringFile or as you had it `teststring`, one per line i.e. if you put `dog` on the first line and `cat` on the second then lines matching dog or cat upto the next blank line, will be cut and pasted in the result file.

Comment: Ahh I see, I was a bit unsure about that, thank you testing now

Comment: It seems to be taking a lot of lines that don't match, and not all lines that do match. Is there any way I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Also would it be possible to add a newline/blankline between every 'section'/match that is cut and pasted?

Comment: To add a blank line in the result file between each match, remove the substitution command `s/.$//;` To trouble shoot, send the regexps created by the first sed invocation into a file.sed and review the contents, then if ok apply it be replacing the `-` following the `-f` option with the file.sed. Good Luck!

Comment: The problem I am having with your solution is the same problem with Jotne's solution; a whole lot of lines that don't contain the term to be matched are getting included, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @JakeRankin sometimes a line may appear empty but still contain spaces. I'll amend the last solution to cater for this and also add a blank line to the result file.

Comment: The matching terms don't seem to be being removed from the original file, although the matching and writing to a new file is working fine, I think the problems are a problem with my data

Comment: For example, 20k will be written to the resultfile, but the original file will only reduce by 6k or so. Maybe only matching not subsequent lines are being removed from the original file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/dog/{count="";found=1} found && ++count<4'  Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Comment: @JakeRankin, thank you Jake. Also I have changed my command which will save output into Input_file itself, let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v RS= '/dog/' file
The best kind of an animal is a dog, for sure
-man's best friend
-related to wolves
```

Comment: Your solution would only test if record contains `dog`, not line starting with `dog`.  Not sure if that is OPs intentions.